# Make image draggable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, draggable

If I add the images through HTML using jquery UI, i have no problem making it draggable.

```
$('#div1 img').draggable({
            containment: '#div1',
});

<div id='div1' class="div1" runat="server" >
     <asp:Image ImageUrl='Images/img1.gif' ID='img1' runat='server'  Height='30px' Width='30px' />
</div>
```

But if I were to add the image from the code behind in the page_load, how would I made it draggable?

```
div1.Controls.Add(new HtmlImage()
                {
                    ID = "img2",
                    Src = "Images/img2.gif",
                    Width = 30,
                    Height = 30
                });
```

Sorry guys, I resolved it:
In the end, This was the cause. I had this in the 
$(this).css("opacity", "1.0");

```
$('#div1 img').draggable({
        containment: '#div1',
        $(this).css("opacity", "1.0");
});
```

Removed the opacity line, resolved my draggable. Sorry guys

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler.

```
$( "#div1" ).on( "click", "img", function( event ){
  $( this ).draggable();
});
```

In a nutshell, attach `on` to an existing parent element of the dynamically loaded image. Next have an event (if you use click you have to first click, then click again to drag so you might want to try a different event) cause the function with your draggable code to be run on any img that is now present.

Comment: Yeah, I purposely added the draggable to all images because the page is based on login, those who do not have the correct login credentials do not get draggable. but for now I am just trying to add draggable after I attach a new image via code behind

Comment: Also I should mention that this div has no images currently. The example in the top was to just show that when i have static images in html, i have no issues making that static image draggable.

Comment: Right. My solution works in the cases you mention. `on` will find your newly added images and make them draggable. Frank, don't forget to up vote solutions you find useful and mark one as "accepted" if it solves your problem.

Comment: I have added this but it has no change on making the image draggable.
I added an alert in this function, at which it does alert when I click the created image, but still is not dragging.
Once I get that image moving, I will mark the appropriate accepted :)

Comment: What happens when you click the image (which applies the function) then click it again to try to drag it?

Comment: it picks up the image as if it were to "cloning", but as I try to drag, my mouse icon turns into the circle with / through it, and after I let go of click, nothing happens

Comment: If I remove the .on event handler, i get the same results.

Comment: ... So I decided to remove all my droppables, clones, dialogs, etc. leaving just the div and the images added in the page loader... and it drags fine... (without the .on() handle event). I guess somewhere in my code it locks it down. Its funny because if I drop images in that same div, it drags just fine, but the moment I refresh my page (persistant elements) i can no longer drag it.

Comment: After editing, found that it was opacity causing the draggable to not work:
$(this).css("opacity", "1.0");

reworked my opacity, now it drags fine after page load.
Sorry for the bother guys :P